# What package to use for automatic display of output with appropriate/short SI unit?

Tags: python-3.x, physics, units-of-measurement

I need a package that can automatically convert units and display them in a shorter form (e.g. instead of 125cm, shows 1.25m). I will be needing this for units of length, volume and some electronic units (4kW instead of 4000W).
I have taken a look at similar posts most of which seem to be old and report problems in even simple calculations.

Comment: I'm afraid questions asking for a recommendation for a library are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) at StackOverflow. [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) might be a more appropriate place for such a question.

Answer (score 0):

[Pint](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/0.9/tutorial.html) is a current Python library with minimal dependencies.

Check out the `to_compact()` method for your use-case.